# Akka+Datastax - Getting error "failed to create a child event loop java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop"

Tags: cassandra, akka, akka-stream, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

basically I am indexing CSV files to Cassandra and after a certain period of time I get this error:

```
failed to create a child event loop
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:50)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:70)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:65)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:56)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil.newEventLoopGroupInstance(NettyUtil.java:139)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyOptions.eventLoopGroup(NettyOptions.java:99)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.<init>(Connection.java:774)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1446)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:330)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:305)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:247)
    at com.dy.scyllaindexer.Indexer_SlaveActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Indexer_SlaveActor.scala:38)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at com.dy.scyllaindexer.Indexer_SlaveActor.aroundReceive(Indexer_SlaveActor.scala:24)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:176)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:150)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:103)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:64)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollCreate(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.<init>(EPollArrayWrapper.java:130)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:69)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:174)
    ... 27 more
```

I run

```
lsof -p MY_PROCESS_ID
```

and I see many many many FIFO pipe are created (thousands)

```
java    16082 my_process *706w     FIFO                0,8       0t0 285381393 
pipe
...
...
thousands
```

My process creates 12 total actors at a given time (6 slave and for each slave another worker )

I'm reading the local CSV file using Akka stream with parallelism of 100 (I have tried to play around with many different values) and writing to cassandra async

code looks similar to this:

```
class SlaveActor(...) extends Actor {
   def receive {
       case DoSomething => {
          val indexer = context.actorOf(CassandraIndexer.props(...))
          val message = Message(...)
          val f = (indexer ? message)
          val ff = f andThen {
             case x: Try[..] => indexer ! PoisonPill ... // force it
          }
          ...

          ff.onComplete {
             case Failure... => {}
             case Success ... => {}
          }
       }
   }
}

class CassandraIndexer (...)  extends Actor{

def receive {
    case Message(...) => 
        implicit val session = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(hosts).withPort(port).build().connect()

        val flow: Sink[Map[String, String], Future[Done]] = Flow[Map[String, String]].mapAsyncUnordered(parallelism = 100) {
      item: Map[String, String] =>
        Future {
            val query = session....bind(item...)
            session.execute(query)
          }
        }
    }.toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.right)

       CsvSourceMaker.createSourceFromFile(csvfile).runWith(flow)

       ... when completed ...
       session.close()

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that I believe are contributing to this:

1. For each `DoSomething` message received by `SlaveActor` you are creating a `CassandraIndexer` actor.  Why not just have 1 `CassandraIndexer` for your `SlaveActor`?
2. It looks like each `Message` received by a `CassandraIndexer` actor instance would create a `Cluster` instance for each message received in the `CassandraIndexer` actor.  A `Cluster` is a relatively heavyweight object, creating a connection pool to each host in your cassandra cluster (see [4 simple rules when using the DataStax drivers for cassandra](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra) for more information).  The socket connections in those connection pools may be the source of many file descriptors being created.

I suggest doing the following:

1. You should only have 1 `CassandraIndexer` actor per `SlaveActor`.
2. You should only have 1 `Cluster` per `CassandraIndexer`, or just 1 `Cluster` overall.

This would limit you to 1 `Cluster` per `SlaveActor`, and reduce the amount of connections to your C* cluster, and it would likely also speed up your application, as `Cluster` initialization would not need to occur every time you execute a query.

Comment: the cassandra indexer is 1x1 to each slave actor, they have state so they need to be a "one time" actor so they are destroyed along with their resources (the cassandra connection and pools). the slave actor only handles one cassandra indexer at a time, so in total there are only 6 indexers actually in existance (max). Seems very reasonable to me

Comment: Creating one-time Cluster instances and closing them afterwards likely leaves a lot of sockets sitting as open descriptors in TIME_WAIT, even after the Cluster is closed, depending on how your OS behaves.

Comment: Really helpful answer! Thanks a million